# Codeigniter V2.x with FB API 4

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a simple facebook web app using CodeIgniter to be able to post to a page linked to my facebook account.

Currently this is my code:

Controller:

```
function facebook(){
    $this->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    $login_url = $this->facebook->get_user();
    echo $login_url;
}
```

Libraries:

I literally use the code pasted here: http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/ (by Ben Marshall).

The library code, by default does not print appropriate Exception. So i had to extend the code so it looks like this (on the constructor):

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->library('session');
        if (!isset($_SESSION)){
            session_start();
        }

        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
            $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'),
            $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook')
        );

        $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($this->ci->config->item('redirect_url', 'facebook'));
        if($this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token')){
            $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token'));

            // Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
            try {
                if (!$this->session->validate()){
                    $this->session = false;
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                // Catch any exceptions
                $this->session = false;
            }

        }else{
            try {
                $this->session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
            }catch(FacebookRequestException $ex){
                echo "<pre> "; print_r($ex->getCode());
                // When Facebook returns an error
            }catch(Exception $ex){ 
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($ex);
                // When validation fails or other local issues
            }
        }

        if ($this->session ){
            $this->ci->session->set_userdata( 'fb_token', $this->session->getToken() );
            $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->getToken());
        }
    }
```

What i did is:
1. I manually start the session, because otherwise i would get an error saying " Session not active, could not load state." With Error Code: 721.

However, even if i had start the session, FacebookRedirectLoginHelper always returns NULL.

After i dig a little deeper, it turns out within the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php, specifically loadState() function always returns NULL.

This is the code for loadState()

```
protected function loadState()
  {
    if ($this->checkForSessionStatus === true
      && session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
      throw new FacebookSDKException(
        'Session not active, could not load state.', 721
      );
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION[$this->sessionPrefix . 'state'])) {
      $this->state = $_SESSION[$this->sessionPrefix . 'state'];
      return $this->state;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Can anyone suggest a possible solution for me? Has anyone successfully develop FB API 4 with CI?

Comment: @seesoe I gave up on this one. Turns out there is no straight forward solution. I ended up creating my own library by making calls to/from this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post API

Comment: I was able to finally figure it out after lots of searching. turns out that the new SDK has 2 functions that call the native php session directly. So you have to extend the class and make it use the codeigniter session instead. Hope this helps anyone that is having this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to write the session_start(); at the start of the page which will start the session on php page.

and also if you can load the facebook library automatically from autoload.php configuration file it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyFacebookRedirectLoginHelper extends \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->ci = & get_instance();
    }

    protected function storeState($state) {
        if ($this->ci->session->set_userdata($this->sessionPrefix . 'state', $state)) {
            $this->state = $this->ci->session->set_userdata($this->sessionPrefix . 'state', $state);
        return $this->state;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    protected function loadState() {
        return $this->state = $this->ci->session->userdata($this->sessionPrefix . 'state');
    }
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/39#issuecomment-42363729